# $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\sqrt x}{x^2-5x+6} \,dx = \frac {\pi}{i \sqrt 3 +i \sqrt 2}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Prove
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\sqrt x}{x^2-5x+6} \,dx = \frac {\pi}{i \sqrt 3 +i \sqrt 2}$$
[Nevermind!]: It has been said, it can be solved in at least three ways.I'm looking forward to seeing two other ways.

Comment: Other than which? Which way do you know already?

Comment: @DanielFischer I already have seen the Mathematica way to solve it.

Comment: @FreeMind - which is?

Comment: Does that mean "hack it into Mathematica and see what it gives you back" or does that mean Mathematica explains how it computes it? If the former, two other ways are "Maple" and "Sage", I think.

Comment: Anyway, the integral does not exist in the Lebesgue or Riemann sense, you should indicate that it is a principal value integral.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's my problem, I don't know how to get around the solution.

Comment: Diverges logarithmically 'around' $x = 2\ \mbox{and}\ x = 3$.

Comment: The purported result, by the way, makes no sense. The integrand is real-valued, so the integral - in every sensible interpretation - ought to be real too.

Answer (score 4):

The given result is wrong, if the integral is interpreted as a principal value integral. It doesn't make sense for any natural interpretation of an integral that the value of a real integral should be a nonzero purely imaginary number anyway, so also for other interpretations, the given result is most likely wrong.

One way to compute the integral (as a principal value integral) is via complex analysis, using the residue theorem:

Take a keyhole contour $C_{\varepsilon,R}$ enveloping the positive real half-axis, with circular deviations around the poles of the integrand in $2$ and $3$ - similar to [image: keyhole contour with deviation around a pole]
but with two circular deviations for the poles. (Image taken from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489555/convergence-of-integral-int-0-infty-frac1x3-1dx) about an integral of a function with a pole.)

Since the contour encloses no singularity of the function, the integral along that contour is $0$. The integrals along the circular parts of the contour tend to $0$ as the radius $\varepsilon$ of the small circular arc around $0$ shrinks to $0$ and the radius $R$ of the large circular arc tends to $+\infty$ by the standard estimate. Since the value of $\sqrt{z}$ as $z$ approaches the positive real half-axis from the lower half plane is the negative of the value as $z$ approaches the positive half-axis from the upper half-plane, the signs from the different orientation on the real axis are cancelled by the sign of the square root, and what remains is

$$\begin{align}
0 &= 2 \int_{M(\varepsilon)} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-5x+6}\,dx\\
&\qquad + \int_0^\pi \frac{\sqrt{2-\varepsilon e^{-it}}}{(-\varepsilon e^{-it})(-\varepsilon e^{-it}-1)}\,d(2-\varepsilon e^{-it}) + \int_0^\pi \frac{\sqrt{3-\varepsilon e^{-it}}}{(1-\varepsilon e^{-it})(-\varepsilon e^{-it})}\,d(3-\varepsilon)\\
&\qquad + \int_0^\pi \frac{\sqrt{2 + \varepsilon e^{-it}}}{\varepsilon e^{-it}(\varepsilon e^{-it}-1)}\, d(2+\varepsilon e^{-it}) + \int_0^\pi \frac{\sqrt{3+\varepsilon e^{-it}}}{(1+\varepsilon e^{-it})\varepsilon e^{-it}}\, d(3+\varepsilon e^{-it}),
\end{align}$$

where $M(\varepsilon) = [0,2-\varepsilon] \cup [2+\varepsilon,3-\varepsilon] \cup [3+\varepsilon, \infty)$.

Now we have to note that for the semicircles in the lower half-plane (the third and fourth of the semicircle integrals) the square root has negative real part, so

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi \frac{\sqrt{2-\varepsilon e^{-it}}}{(-\varepsilon e^{-it})(-\varepsilon e^{-it}-1)}\,d(2-\varepsilon e^{-it})&\; + \int_0^\pi \frac{\sqrt{2 + \varepsilon e^{-it}}}{\varepsilon e^{-it}(\varepsilon e^{-it}-1)}\, d(2+\varepsilon e^{-it})\\
&= i\int_0^\pi \frac{\sqrt{2-\varepsilon e^{-it}}}{1+\varepsilon e^{-it}} + \frac{\sqrt{2+\varepsilon e^{-it}}}{1-\varepsilon e^{-it}}\,dt
\end{align}$$

tends to $0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, and similarly for the semicircles around $3$, whence we obtain

$$\operatorname{v.p.} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-5x+6}\,dx = 0.$$

Another way to compute the same result is to determine a local primitive of the integrand on each of the intervals $(0,2)$, $(2,3)$, and $(3,\infty)$. Since

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-5x+6} = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{(x-3)(x-2)} = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-3} - \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-2},$$

a little fiddling leads to the primitive

$$\sqrt{3}\log \left\lvert \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{3}}\right\rvert - \sqrt{2} \log \left\lvert \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2}}\right\rvert$$

on each of the above intervals. Then one can compute the integrals over the intervals $(\varepsilon,2-\varepsilon)$, $(2+\varepsilon,3-\varepsilon)$ and $(3+\varepsilon,\infty)$ explicitly, sum them, and take the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$ to once again obtain

$$\operatorname{v.p.} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-5x+6}\,dx = 0.$$

Comment: very nice computation.  Congratulations.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Your answer is awesome, is it possible to give picture (geometric) way of those paths and circles that you're integrating, I don't know contour integration, is it possible to learn the integration without diving into Complex Analysis?

Comment: @FreeMind I've added an image of a similar contour to show how it roughly looks. I don't think learning to use the residue theorem to evaluate integrals without learning some complex analysis works well, but you don't need to learn a terrible lot of complex analysis for that, the residue theorem is more the basis of much of the theory than an application.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is using the residue theorem.  First make the change of variable $x = u^2$ then we have

$$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {\sqrt {x}}{{x}^{2}-5\,x+6}}{dx}=2\,\int _
{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {{u}^{2}}{{u}^{4}-5\,{u}^{2}+6}}{du}=\int _{-
\infty }^{\infty }\!{\frac {{u}^{2}}{{u}^{4}-5\,{u}^{2}+6}}{du}
$$

The last integral is converted into a contour integral and it is evaluated using the residue theorem:

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\!{\frac {{u}^{2}}{{u}^{4}-5\,{u}^{2}+6}}{du
}=2\,i\pi \, \left( {\it Res} \left( {\frac {{u}^{2}}{{u}^{4}-5\,{u}^{
2}+6}},u=-\sqrt {3} \right) +{\it Res} \left( {\frac {{u}^{2}}{{u}^{4}
-5\,{u}^{2}+6}},u=-\sqrt {2} \right)+{\it Res} \left( {\frac {{u}^{2}}{{u}^{4}
-5\,{u}^{2}+6}},u=\sqrt {2} \right)+{\it Res} \left( {\frac {{u}^{2}}{{u}^{4}
-5\,{u}^{2}+6}},u=\sqrt {3} \right)  \right)$$

Computing the residues we obtain

$$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {\sqrt {x}}{{x}^{2}-5\,x+6}}{dx}=0
$$

This result was checked using Mathematica with the command

```
Integrate[Sqrt[x]/(x^2 - 5*x + 6), {x, 0, ∞}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

Thanks to @DanielFischer by the corrections.

Comment: I don't agree. We also have the residues in $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, which you need to add. Your transformed integrand is an even function, so the residues are "odd", and thus the residues add to $0$, which yields $$\operatorname{v.p.} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u^2}{u^4-5u^2+6}\,du = 0.$$ Incidentally, that makes much more sense than a purely imaginary value of a real integral.

Comment: @DanielFischer you are very right.  Many thanks.